# HTML button not resizing

Tags: html, button, input

The button remains the length of the page, why will it not reduce to 50x50px? I want the code to be inline as I have it with the button.
But as you can see in the image the button does not resize. I would just like a smaller button that does not span the entire page, and centered.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>MySite</title>
    <link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <style>



    </style>

    </head>
    <body>

    <div data-role="page">
      <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Homepage</h1>
      </div>
      <br />
      <br />
      <input type="seach" id="mySearch" placeholder="quick search" align="center">
      <button onClick="searchFunction()" align="right" style="height:50px; width:50px;">Search</button>
      <br />
      <br />
        <a href="#signIn">Sign In</a>
        <p><strong>Welcome!</strong></p>
        <a href="#course" data-transition="fade">Course</a>
        <br>
        <a href="#videoTutorials">Video Tutorials</a>
        <br>
        <a href="#forumsChat" data-transition="fade">Forums / Chat</a>
        <br>
        <a href="#directory" data-transition="fade">Directory</a>
        <br>
        <a href="#additionalResources" data-transition="fade">Additional Resources</a>
      </div>
    <div>
      <div data-role="footer">
        <h1>Mobile web app for Students!</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id="signIn">
      <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Sign In</h1>
      </div>

      <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <p>In your to ensure the best experience and you recieve content specifically for you, please sign in.</p>
        <br>

        <form>
          <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="textinput">Email: </label>
            <input type="text" name="textinput" id="textinput" value=""  />
          </div>
          <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="passwordinput">Password: </label>
            <input type="password" name="passwordinput" id="passwordinput" value=""  />
          </div>
          <button>Sign In</button>    

        </form>

      </div>

    </div>

    <div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id="course">
      <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Course</h1>
      </div>

      <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <p>Welcome! Here you will find contect about your course. You will need to log in to view specific information related to your course.</p>
        <br>

      </div>

    </div>

    <div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id="videoTutorials">
      <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Video Tutorials</h1>
      </div>

      <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <p>Welcome! Here you will find different video tutorials that will help your knowldge of programming grow. You will find different catagories such as Web Development and Game Programming. ENJOY!</p>
        <br />
        <hr>
        <h1>Web Development</h1>
        <p align="center">HTML5</p>
        <p align="center">(from thenewboston.com)</p>
        <p align="center"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Mp0f0zTPLec" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></p>
        <br />
        <p align="center">JavaScript</p>
        <p align="center">(from thenewboston.com)</p>
        <p align="center"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/yQaAGmHNn9s" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></p>
        <br />
        <p align="center">CSS</p>
        <p align="center">(from EJ Media on YouTube)</p>
        <p align="center"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qKoajPPWpmo?list=PLr6-GrHUlVf8JIgLcu3sHigvQjTw_aC9C" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></p>
        <br />
        <hr>
        <h1>Game Programming</h1>
        <p align="center">C++ in Unreal Engine</p>
        <p align="center">(from Unreal Engine on YouTube)</p>
        <p align="center"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mSRov77hNR4?list=PLZlv_N0_O1gYup-gvJtMsgJqnEB_dGiM4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></p>

      </div>

    </div>

    <div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id="forumsChat">
      <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Forums / Chat</h1>
      </div>

      <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <p>Welcome! Here you will be able to stay in touch with your fellow students. You can see who is on chatting now, or start a conversation in the forums.</p>
        <br />

      </div>

    </div>

    <div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id="directory">
      <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Directory</h1>
      </div>

      <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <p>Welcome! Here you will be able to find information for your current professors and fellow students. You will need to log in first in order to see information pertaining to you. Without logging in you will see general contact information for the school and administration contact information</p>
        <br />
        <hr>
        <h1>General</h1>
        <br />
        <p>Visit Rasmussen college: <a href="http://www.rasmussen.edu/" target="_blank">Rasmussen Site</a></p>
        <p>Call: 888-549-6755</p>
        <br />
        <h2>Rasmussen Location</h2>
        <p align="left"><a href="#floridaDialog">Florida</a></p>
        <p align="left"><a href="#kansasDialog">Kansas</a></p>

      </div>

    </div>

    <div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id="additionalResources">
      <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Additional Resources</h1>
      </div>

      <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <p>Welcome! Here you will find additional resources to help you grow. You will find links and videos to various toppics in computer science; such as programming, networking etc..</p>
        <br />

      </div>

    </div>

    <div data-role="page" data-dialog="true" data-add-back-btn="true" id="kansasDialog">
      <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Kansas</h1>
      </div>
      <h2>Topika</h2>
      <p>620 SW Governor View<br>Topeka, KS 66606<br>785-228-7320</p>
      <hr>
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" data-dialog="true" data-add-back-btn="true" id="floridaDialog">
      <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Florida</h1>
      </div>
      <h2>Fort Myers</h2>
      <p>9160 Forum Corporate Parkway<br>Suite 100<br>Fort Myers, FL 33905</p>
      <p>239-477-2100<br>866-344-0229</p>
      <hr>
    </div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

[image]

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: That's not a minimal example. And if you had done a LITTLE bit of testing, you would see that the style in the example and the link is not a default look for a button, and that's because you include the jquery-CSS in the file. That overrides the inline-styles (which means that the CSS in question probably styles the button using `!important` on the rules. Regardless - don't use CSS-files you don't control, remove the stylesheet, and the `width` and `height` works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
        <link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
  
        </head>
        <body>

          <br />
       
       <style>
       .container {
        display: flex;
    }
       </style>
       <div class="container">
        <div>
           <input type="seach" id="mySearch" placeholder="quick search" align="center">
        </div>
        <div>
        <button onClick="searchFunction()" style="height:50px; width:50px;">Search</button>
        </div>
    </div>
       
       
       
       
       
       
       
       
          <br />
          <br />
            <a href="#signIn">Sign In</a>
            <p><strong>Welcome!</strong></p>
            <a href="#course" data-transition="fade">Course</a>
            <br>
            <a href="#videoTutorials">Video Tutorials</a>
            <br>
            <a href="#forumsChat" data-transition="fade">Forums / Chat</a>
            <br>
            <a href="#directory" data-transition="fade">Directory</a>
            <br>
            <a href="#additionalResources" data-transition="fade">Additional Resources</a>
          </div>
        <div>
          <div data-role="footer">
            <h1>Mobile web app for Students!</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
    
        <div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id="signIn">
          <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Sign In</h1>
          </div>
    
          <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <p>In your to ensure the best experience and you recieve content specifically for you, please sign in.</p>
            <br>
    
            <form>
              <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="textinput">Email: </label>
                <input type="text" name="textinput" id="textinput" value=""  />
              </div>
              <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="passwordinput">Password: </label>
                <input type="password" name="passwordinput" id="passwordinput" value=""  />
              </div>
              <button>Sign In</button>    
    
            </form>
    
          </div>
    
        </div>
    
        <div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id="course">
          <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Course</h1>
          </div>
    
          <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <p>Welcome! Here you will find contect about your course. You will need to log in to view specific information related to your course.</p>
            <br>
    
          </div>
    
        </div>
    
        <div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id="videoTutorials">
          <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Video Tutorials</h1>
          </div>
    
          <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <p>Welcome! Here you will find different video tutorials that will help your knowldge of programming grow. You will find different catagories such as Web Development and Game Programming. ENJOY!</p>
            <br />
            <hr>
            <h1>Web Development</h1>
            <p align="center">HTML5</p>
            <p align="center">(from thenewboston.com)</p>
            <p align="center"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Mp0f0zTPLec" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></p>
            <br />
            <p align="center">JavaScript</p>
            <p align="center">(from thenewboston.com)</p>
            <p align="center"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/yQaAGmHNn9s" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></p>
            <br />
            <p align="center">CSS</p>
            <p align="center">(from EJ Media on YouTube)</p>
            <p align="center"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qKoajPPWpmo?list=PLr6-GrHUlVf8JIgLcu3sHigvQjTw_aC9C" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></p>
            <br />
            <hr>
            <h1>Game Programming</h1>
            <p align="center">C++ in Unreal Engine</p>
            <p align="center">(from Unreal Engine on YouTube)</p>
            <p align="center"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mSRov77hNR4?list=PLZlv_N0_O1gYup-gvJtMsgJqnEB_dGiM4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></p>
    
          </div>
    
        </div>
    
        <div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id="forumsChat">
          <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Forums / Chat</h1>
          </div>
    
          <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <p>Welcome! Here you will be able to stay in touch with your fellow students. You can see who is on chatting now, or start a conversation in the forums.</p>
            <br />
    
          </div>
    
        </div>
    
        <div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id="directory">
          <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Directory</h1>
          </div>
    
          <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <p>Welcome! Here you will be able to find information for your current professors and fellow students. You will need to log in first in order to see information pertaining to you. Without logging in you will see general contact information for the school and administration contact information</p>
            <br />
            <hr>
            <h1>General</h1>
            <br />
            <p>Visit Rasmussen college: <a href="http://www.rasmussen.edu/" target="_blank">Rasmussen Site</a></p>
            <p>Call: 888-549-6755</p>
            <br />
            <h2>Rasmussen Location</h2>
            <p align="left"><a href="#floridaDialog">Florida</a></p>
            <p align="left"><a href="#kansasDialog">Kansas</a></p>
    
          </div>
    
        </div>
    
        <div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id="additionalResources">
          <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Additional Resources</h1>
          </div>
    
          <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <p>Welcome! Here you will find additional resources to help you grow. You will find links and videos to various toppics in computer science; such as programming, networking etc..</p>
            <br />
    
          </div>
    
        </div>
    
        <div data-role="page" data-dialog="true" data-add-back-btn="true" id="kansasDialog">
          <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Kansas</h1>
          </div>
          <h2>Topika</h2>
          <p>620 SW Governor View<br>Topeka, KS 66606<br>785-228-7320</p>
          <hr>
        </div>
    
        <div data-role="page" data-dialog="true" data-add-back-btn="true" id="floridaDialog">
          <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Florida</h1>
          </div>
          <h2>Fort Myers</h2>
          <p>9160 Forum Corporate Parkway<br>Suite 100<br>Fort Myers, FL 33905</p>
          <p>239-477-2100<br>866-344-0229</p>
          <hr>
        </div>
```